# Set NLS_DATE_FORMAT in oracle 11g to truncate time if it is not present

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a SELECT query in PLSQL that contains multiple DATE columns and some of them also include TIME in it. The date and time must be displayed in standard format i.e; **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM** So before executing the query I set NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter:

`ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';`

The problem here is that those columns which only have a DATE in it (without TIME) also shows a default time in result set i.e; 12:00:00 AM

[image]

*Is there a way in oracle to setup NLS_DATE_FORMAT param in way that it truncates default time if it isn't present in DATE filed?*

Note that I am aware of methods like TO_CHAR and TRUNC to achieve the desired results but in my case I can't use these because it will affect data sorting in my application.

Comment: I can't say if it's something new in 19c but 11g does not have a column type that can store dates without times.

Comment: neither 19c. one thing is how dates are stored and something altogether different is how they are displayed.

Comment: @asim-ishaq : those dates you refer in your question. Are they coming from variables or from columns in tables ? If those values are from tables, are they stored as varchar2 ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez They are coming from a table in a simple select statement and values are stored in DATE data type.

Comment: NLS settings at session level apply to each and every single column and always in the same format. there is no way as far as I know to achieve this without applying some function like trunc or to_char

Comment: You can not have a DATE value without a time in Oracle.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez is there a way to know if time is also stored with date in DATE field ?

Comment: it is always stored, always.

Comment: Using to_char and trunc should not affect your sorting, because you should not sort (ORDER BY) on the result, but rather on the original column.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no way to achieve this by NLS_SETTINGS**. NLS_DATE_FORMAT specifies the default date format to use with the TO_CHAR and TO_DATE functions and applies to each and every single column. The default value of this parameter is determined by NLS_TERRITORY.

The value of this parameter can be any valid date format mask, and the value must be surrounded by double quotation marks.

Oracle always stores the time, but it will show it as long as the date format specified provides a date/time mask

Example

```
SQL> create table mytest ( c1 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into mytest values ( to_date ( '22/07/2020 11:25:00 AM' , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' ) ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into mytest values ( to_date ( '22/07/2020' , 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from mytest ;

C1
---------
22-JUL-20
22-JUL-20

SQL> select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' ;

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from mytest ;

C1
----------------------
22/07/2020 11:25:00 AM
22/07/2020 12:00:00 AM

SQL>
```

You have to apply some function ( TRUNC or TO_CHAR ) in order to achieve what you want. Oracle always store the time.

Comment: @asim-ishaq, may you be so kind to accept the answer ? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Oracle dates (as long as we're talking about actual dates and not just text) **always** have a time component.

I suspect the confusion arouses because you can feed `DATE` columns with texts that contain dates but not time. What really happens here is that ANSI date literals and the `TO_DATE()` function will just store a default value for missing components. In this case, **midnight**:

```
create table test (
    id int not null,
    value date not null,
    primary key (id)
);
insert into test (id, value) values (1, date'2020-07-22');
insert into test (id, value) values (2, to_date('2020-07-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
select id, value as default_format, to_char(value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as custom_format
from test;
```

([Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d800f3e67ca68ef85e9783db2df0ec17))

If you *really* need it you can write a custom formatting function that checks if time is midnight and omits it, but of course there's just no way to tell whether the value was the default one or it's part of actual data explicitly entered that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily obtained by specifying the the desired date format and **NOT** relying on nls_date_format. Further you can conditionally format the result yes sort date/time correctly.

```
with x (date_col) as 
    ( select trunc(sysdate) from dual union all 
      select sysdate - 1 from dual
    )
 select  
        case when to_char(date_col, 'hh24:mi:ss') = '00:00:00' 
             then to_char(date_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
             else to_char(date_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss am')
        end date_col
   from x 
  order by date_col;
```